# Is the complexity of prim's MST algorithm by adjacency matrix same as that of adjacency list with linear search?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

From my understanding, the use of heap helps by allowing constant cost for finding minimum value with the extra work of `log n` every time we change a value. Change in value can happen a maximum of `e` times. Time complexity is approximately `O(e) + O(e log n) = O(e log n)`.
If it is a dense graph, `e = n^2`.

But if we do the searching for minimum using linear search on the `value array`, we will get a complexity of `O(e) + O(n^2) = O(n^2)` which is better than `elog n` for dense graphs. This is similar to what we get from using a 2D array for graph representation in prim's MST algorithm.
Then why do we use the 2D array representation at all for this specific algorithm?

`e` = number of edges.

`n` = number of nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right; there's no point in using a fancy heap data structure for Prim on dense graphs. The defining feature of Prim, though, is not the heap so much as the idea of repeatedly extending a partial MST as cheaply as possible.

The point of an adjacency matrix is for space (no pointer overhead) and architectural reasons (sequential accesses are typically much more efficient than random).

Comment: My question was about the use of adjacency matrix versus adjacency list. From what it appears to me, the complexity of using linear search + adjacency list in Prim's MST algorithm is asymptotically same as using adjacency matrix method (both being n^2). Then why do we use the adjacency matrix at all? If the question seems unclear, please suggest any changes. EDIT: Sorry, misunderstood your answer. You are referring to adjacency list + linear search in case of dense graphs, right?

Comment: @aste123 OK, extended my answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Got it. So, if it's sparse graph, we can ofcourse get better time complexity by using adjacency list + heap. For dense, adjacency list + linear search and adjacency matrix + linear search, both give same complexity asymptotically but adjacency matrix helps with no pointer overhead, etc so that is preferred. Thank you.